# Make a router like zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a url http://*****.com/branch/module/view/id/1/cat/2/etc/3.

It becomes.

```
array
(
  'module'=>'branch',
  'controller'=>'module',
  'action'=>'view'
);
```

next I need to get the params.
Ihave this array.

```
/*function getNextSegments($n,$segments) {
    return array_slice ( $q = $this->segments, $n + 1 );
}
$params =   getNextSegments(3);
 */
 array ( 0 => 'id', 1 => '1', 2 => 'cat', 3 => '2', 4 => 'etc', 5 => '3' );//params
```

And i wanna convert it to this one: 
array
(
  'id'=>1,
  'cat'=>2,
  'etc'=>3,
);

How i can do this using php function. I know I can do using for or foreach, but I think php has such function , but i cant find it :(.
Thank you.

```
  class A {
    protected function combine($params) {

        $count = count ( $params );
        $returnArray = array ();

        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 2) {
            $g = $i % 2;
            if ($g == 0 or $g > 0) {
                if (isset ( $params [$i] ) and isset ( $params [$i + 1] ))
                    $returnArray [$params [$i]] = $params [$i + 1];
            }
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }

}
```

This works normaly. If anybody has better logic for this  please help.
Thank you again.

Comment: Where are you getting that array from?

Comment: I have edited the question, now you can see where I am getting it.

Comment: Since you've tagged this with ZF, can you not just do `$this->_getAllParams()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not have a built-in function for this. I would just implement it with explode and a loop, shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: No it is not hard .I thought that php has such function .

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like this in my extended Zend_Controller_Action class.

```
public function getCleanParams()
{
    $removeElements = array(
        'module' => '',
        'controller' => '',
        'action' => '',
        '_dc' => ''
    );
    return array_diff_key($this->_request->getParams(), $removeElements);
}
```

That will give you your parameters in a clean fashion and the format you want it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can start building your router with the following regular expression (name the file index.php):

```
<?php

$pattern = '@^(?P<module>branch)/'.
           '(?P<controller>module)/'.
           '(?P<action>view)'.
           '(:?/id[s]?/(?P<id>[0-9]+))?'.
           '(:?/cat[s]?/(?P<cat>[0-9]+))?'.
           '(:?/etc[s]?/(?P<etc>[0-9]+))?@ui';

preg_match($pattern, trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), $segment);

echo sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>', var_export($segment, true));
```

Assuming you have PHP 5.4.x installed, you can type the following on the command-line:

```
% php -S localhost:8765
```

Now browse to http://localhost:8765/branch/module/view/id/1/cat/2/etc/3

The output will be (removed numeric keys except 0 for clarity):

```
array (
  0 => 'branch/module/view/id/1/cat/2/etc/3',
  'module' => 'branch',
  'controller' => 'module',
  'action' => 'view',
  'id' => '1',
  'cat' => '2',
  'etc' => '3',
)
```

Comment: I have router like this one. The  problem is that id can be ids and so on the uri can be http://*.com/branch/module/view/ids/1/cats/2/etcs/3
So now I need {ids} this way I have to make another route for it.

Comment: I've updated the regex so you can have segments named "id" or "ids" and "cat" or "cats"...